# How to count number of tweets via Twitter API

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Is it possible to send a request to Twitter API, just to count number of tweets between two dates?

```py
settings = {
    'search_words': ['#BTC' or 'Bitcoin' or '$BTC'],
    'date_since': "2021-04-09",
    'date_until': "2021-04-16"
}
```

and then get just the number of tweets in a mentioned time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paid premium 30 day search API has a count function. The standard 7 day search API does not have this feature and you have to count the Tweets returned for yourself.